# Defaults if player doesn't already have gems

Tags: java, mysql

### **Follow up question from** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889696/cant-set-defaults-in-mysql)

Here is my current code, I try to preform the check to see if they have any tokens and then set the tokens if they dont but it seems to just be running the code no matter if I set it or not.

```
@EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) throws SQLException {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    String name = player.getName();
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE PlayerName = '" + name + "';");
    res.next();

    int tokens = 0;

    if (res.getString("PlayerName") == null) {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tokens (`PlayerName`, `tokens`) VALUES ('" + name + "', '0');");

        tokens = 1000;
    } else {
        tokens = res.getInt("tokens");
    }

    player.sendMessage(tokens + " Tokens.");
}
```

Comment: First thing to fix before *anything* else - stop putting your values straight into SQL. Use parameterized SQL. See http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you check for a row's existence is wrong. Take a look at your query:

```
"SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE PlayerName = '" + name + "'
```

If a player does not exist in the table, this query will return 0 rows, not a row with `null` for the player's name, like you're checking now. Instead, you should check if the `ResultSet` has a row:

```
ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE PlayerName = '" + name + "';");

int tokens = 0;

if (res.next()) {
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tokens (`PlayerName`, `tokens`) VALUES ('" + name + "', '0');");

    tokens = 1000;
} else {
    tokens = res.getInt("tokens");
}
```